# Golang equivalent of npm install -g

Tags: go, npm, bin, npm-install, goinstall

If I had a compiled Golang program that I wanted to install such that I could run it with a bash command from anywhere on my computer, how would I do that?  For example, in nodejs

```
npm install -g express
```

Installs express such that I can run the command

```
express myapp
```

and express will generate a file directory for a node application called "myapp" in whatever my current directory is.  Is there an equivalent command for go?  I believe now with the "go install" command you have to be in the directory that contains the executable in order to run it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you add GOPATH/bin to your PATH? (or are you looking for some sort of [go package manager](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools)?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no direct equivalent to `npm install -g`. The closest equivalent would not be `go install`, but `go get`. From the help page (`go help get`):

> usage: `go get [-d] [-f] [-fix] [-insecure] [-t] [-u] [build flags] [packages]`
>
> Get downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths,
>   along with their dependencies.

By default, `go get` installs binaries to `$GOPATH/bin`, so the easiest way to make those binaries callable from everywhere is to add that directory to your `$PATH`.

For this, put the following line into your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc`, depending on which shell you're using):

```
export PATH="$PATH:$GOPATH/bin"
```

---

Alternatively, you could also copy or link the executables to `/usr/local/bin`:

```
ln -s $GOPATH/bin/some-binary /usr/local/bin/some-binary
```

Comment: At the time this was correct (and thank you for your help) but it's worth noting for anyone who comes across this question that there is now a `go install` that builds a binary and puts it in your `$GOPATH/bin`

Comment: I have to install all the dependencies listed in the go.mod file.

I can do it one my one using the go get command, but is there any other alternative to this? Something like npm i and it installs the required dependencies all at once.

Answer (score 51):

Update: If you're using Go 1.16, this answer still works, but `go install` has changed and is now the recommended method for installing executable packages. See Karim's answer for an explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559728/10490740

Using Go >= 1.11, if your current directory is within a module-based project, or you've set `GO111MODULE=on` in your environment, `go get` will not install packages "globally". It will add them to your project's go.mod file instead.

As of Go 1.11.1, setting `GO111MODULE=off` works to circumvent this behavior:

```
GO111MODULE=off go get github.com/usr/repo
```

Basically, by disabling the module feature for this single command, it will install to GOPATH as expected.

Projects not using modules can still `go get` normally to install binaries to `$GOPATH/bin`.

There's a lengthy conversation and multiple issues logged about this change in behavior branching from here: [golang/go - cmd/go: go get should not add a dependency to go.mod #27643](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27643).

Comment: This is the information I was looking for, you got it!

Comment: With Go 1.17 GOPATH and GO111MODULE will be removed. Do you know how to handle it in this case?

Comment: Sasha, you can use `go install package@version` starting from Go 1.16. I've added details in the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/68559728/844134

Answer (score 36):

Starting with Go >= **1.16** the recommended way to install an executable is to use

```
go install package@version
```

For example, `go install github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@latest`.

Executables (main packages) are installed to the directory named by the `GOBIN` environment variable, which defaults to `$GOPATH/bin` or `$HOME/go/bin` if the `GOPATH` environment variable is not set. You need to add this directory to your `PATH` variable to run executables globally. In my case, I've added this line to my `~/.zshrc` file. (if you are using bash, add it to the `~/.bash_profile` file):

```
export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"
```

Go team published a [blog post](https://blog.golang.org/go116-module-changes#TOC_4.) about this change, here's the explanation quote:

> We used to recommend go get -u program to install an executable, but this use caused too much confusion with the meaning of go get for adding or changing module version requirements in go.mod.

Refer to [`go install` documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-install) for more details

Comment: I am using go 1.19, I have GO111MODULE=on and GOMODCACHE set to some directory - $HOME/go/pkg/mod. I see go install <package>@version is downloading in GOMODCACHE directory.  Why is this happening any idea?

Answer (score 11):

Short solution for Linux users:

1. Use the `go get` command as usual
2. Add the following lines to `.bashrc`:

```sh
# This is the default GOPATH, you should confirm with the 'go env' command
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

1. Restart terminal or source it. Installed binaries will be available globally.

For Go v1.8+

1. `go install package_name@latest`

Comment: This solution will work on linux, macos (and/or .zshrc) and git-bash for windows as well

Answer (score 5):

> Caveat: this answer is outdated following [the 2020 deprecation of `go get`](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation). The solution presented here won't work with newer Go runtime installs.

The closest analogue of this in Go would be `go get`. By default, it will fetch a Go package from a supplied repository URL, and requires a `$GOPATH` variable to be set in your shell so that Go knows where to store the packages (and subsequently where to find them when compiling code depending on `go get`-ted packages).

Example syntax:

```
$ go get github.com/user/repo
```

The behaviour supplied by `npm`'s `-g` flag is default, and packages installed using `go get` are normally available globally.

See `go get --help` for more information about the command.

As mentioned by @helmbert, adding your `$GOPATH` to your `$PATH` is useful if you're installing standalone packages.

Comment: When I use this, the go/bin folder is invariant. Is there anywhere else the files could go?

Comment: @kendfss a bit late to the party (and I imagine you've found a solution by now), but at some point between this answer and your comment, Go saw a fairly major rework of how packages are vendored. Most notably, [`go get` is deprecated since 2020](https://go.dev/doc/go-get-install-deprecation). I haven't used Go as a main programming language in a while so I can't give much more advice beyond following that official doc.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using zsh :

first: install your package using :

```
go install package@version
```

then , you edit your .zshrc file

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add this line to the end of .zshrc file :

```
export PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"
```

last but not least :

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

then open a new terminal and execute your command :)

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR* at the bottom. I'm going to walk you through how I came to this conclusion, and why the more obvious solutions don't work.

---

Upon seeing this question, I thought *"If I could set root's `GOPATH=/usr`, it would install things in `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/src`!"*

So I tried the obvious thing:

1. **Add `GOPATH=/usr` to root's `.bashrc`.**
   And it worked!
   Sort of.
   Not really.
   Turns out, `sudo` doesn't execute root's `.bashrc`. For "security" or something like that.
2. **Do `env_set` or something in `/etc/sudoers`**
   Turns out, `/etc/sudoers` can only *remove* environment variables. There's no `env_set` directive.
   <sup>(As far as I can find)</sup>
3. **Dig through `man sudoers`.**
   Where does sudo get it's default set of environment variables from?
   Well, the first one in the list is `/etc/environment`, so that's the one I used.

---

```
sudo echo "GOPATH=/usr" >> /etc/environment
sudo go get <repo>
```

Binaries will be put in `/usr/bin`, and sources will be put in `/usr/src`.

Running go as non-root will use GOPATH the "normal" way.

Comment: you could also `GOPATH=/` and install in `/bin` and `/src`.

Comment: Typically, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` should only be modified by your distro package manager. `/usr/local` is a much better place to put system-wide modifications. You won't accidentally step on your package manager's toes, and permissions are often more amenable to unprivileged alteration (e.g., on macOS).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have go installed, you may use the [gobinaries](https://gobinaries.com/). it builds an on-demand binary of the project from github repo.

The command to install the go package would be:

```sh
curl -sf https://gobinaries.com/rakyll/hey | sh
```